# Find the macro that affects a particular cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'd be happy to get help from the experts:

How can I find all the commands, models and forms that affect a particular cell?

It will not help to look for the cell in the macro, because there is a range name that includes this cell.

I would be happy to receive information / directions / concepts.

If it is not clear enough please write to me.

Comment: I think you are asking x but mean y. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you [edit] your question and add more detailed information about the overall purpose or show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no general way to find **all** things that affect a particular cell automatically.

If there are only a view cells to test you can use the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) with a `Stop` command on the target cell.

Example:
This stops when the value of range A2 is changed by a macro or user interaction

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Stop
End Sub
```

Then you can run your macro to test if it interacts with that cell. It will stop at the event. Then you can use F8 to go step by step and find out which code triggered the change event. But this will only trigger value changes but not changes on format etc.

Comment: I think your code is right for me, but the macro I'm testing will not apply the code changes because you can not go back

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the issue. You need to be more specific. And what is *"not go back"*? You mean in the code? You can go forward with F8 and and the point you leave the event `Worksheet_Change` at `End Sub` it will return to the macro that triggered the event.

Comment: You mean that `but not changes on format etc` will not apply the commands of the macro I'm testing

Comment: If your macro changes eg the color of that cell, the event will not trigger

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, but I have to remember to delete the code, if I want to get back to routine ... Otherwise, I will not understand why my codes do not work:)

Comment: Of course this is only for testing and not for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture macro that modified the values try below code:

```
Public macroName As String

Sub SomeMacro()
    'store the name in global variable
    macroName = "SomeMacro"
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "new value!"
End Sub

Sub AnotherMacro()
    'store the name in global variable
    macroName = "AnotherMacro"
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "other new value!"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' here you check what cell was modified,
    ' if it's not the one interesting us, exit sub
    If Target.Address <> "$A$1" Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox "Cell A1 modified by " & macroName
End Sub
```

You simply store name of executing macro in global variable (which you **must** set at beginning of every macro) and in event of change, you have information what macro just modified cell of interest.